# When moving an existing DB to use flyway, does the baseline migration need to contain the DDL of all the existing tables?

Tags: flyway

I am adding flyway to control all modifications to an existing DB via flyway (remove human contact). The only purpose I would use flyway for will be to modify or add tables and maybe some data insertions (DML). I want to know whether or not I need to have my baseline migration script contain the DDL of the existing database? Or can it just be empty? I do have `baselineOnMigrate = true` set.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you do not require reproducibility, i.e. ability to ship entire database including everything before the baseline to another box, then no, it is not required, but is recommended as stated [here](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/learnmore/existing).